# Alternate Library

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm wanting to rearrange table columns dynamically.

I can do the actual rearrange but for the dragging of the header cells I'm wanting something that feels like jqueryui's sortable elements with the placeholder http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder (obviously horizontally rather than vertically though)

The problem is that I don't want to use jquery (javascript is fine but jquery is too heavy), does anyone know of something more lightweight that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/sites/default/files/99/source/SOTC-DnDLists.js

It's not horizontal but I'm sure it can be worked with...

[update: Indeed, minor modifications made this work like a charm - code will follow]

Answer (score 1):

Anything that can handle the complexities of drag-and-drop is going to be big. JavaScript libraries usually try to solve simple things, like DOM selectors and AJAX, then other UI functionality, like sliders, animation and drag-drop are added on top of these.

So finding small a library that does the drag-and-drop alone is unlikely. There are alternatives, such as [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/), but you'll find they aren't smaller.

Keep in mind that **jQuery isn't all that big - smaller than many images you'd use on your site.** It is also cached by the browser, so it doesn't have to be downloaded with every page load.

Comment: Seriously dude, jquery is much heavier on the cpu doing all its muck than a library that's designed for a specific purpose. I'm working on slower hardware and it's not in an actual browser - the lighter the better. All the javascript that is required in the link I have posted amounts to 8.1k uncompressed (with my modifications).

Comment: That is often true but less code that is good is faster than more code that is good. Please don't tell me that jquery + ui + placeholder code is better than coding just to do the one thing you want from the ui.

Comment: The only way is to test it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://microjs.com/ Type in what you need and it will help you narrow down a list of libraries.

Comment: Thanks DmitryB, I had a look but didn't find anything, it's a useful resource though...